# androidstudio 3.4.2 (macosx) add module dependency dialog empty

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

After upgrade android studio to 3.4.2 today (macosx), I create a android project and import a opencv module successfully. but when I try to add opecv module to my module (app), the add module dependency dialog is always empty, nothing can be selected:

[image]

Comment: Which folder of your dowloaded "OpenCV-android-sdk" do you import as a module? Can you show the build.gradle file from your openCVLibrary410?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to follow to import OpenCV 4.1.0 as an external module in Android Studio 3.4.2 :

1. Download [OpenCV 4.1.0 Android release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download), unzip downloaded file and put *OpenCV-android-sdk* directory on a path of your choice, for example */Users/Example/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk*.
2. Open *setting.gradle* file and append these two lines :

   `include ':opencv'
    project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(opencvsdk + '/sdk')`
3. Open *gradle.properties* file and append following line (Do not forget to use correct OpenCV Android SDK path for your machine) :

   `opencvsdk=/Users/Example/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk`
4. Open your app *build.gradle* file and add `implementation project(path: ':opencv')` to dependencies section :

   `dependencies {
           ...
           implementation project(path: ':opencv')
       }`
5. Click on `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

For complete instructions on how to set up OpenCV with Android Studio, you can have a look at my [Github repository](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue before.it caused by the opencv4.1.0 sdk. if you import it to android studio, no error report but actually it missed something.
After fallback to official opencv3.4.2 release. it works fine now.

Maybe opencv4.1.0 version still not stable version. so don't use it.